# Logistic regression gives me precision of 0.55. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python, pandas

Copied columns from data frame Z, made dummies, trying to predict Click, a 0/1 variable. Balanced size of train and test. Where did I go wrong?

```
    df = z[['user_state', 'device_maker', 'day_of_week', 'device_area_zscore', 'Age_zscore', 'consumption_zscore', 'click']].copy()
    
    day_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df["day_of_week"])
    state_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df["user_state"])
    maker_dummy = pd.get_dummies(df["device_maker"])
    
    combined_df = pd.concat([df, day_dummy, state_dummy, maker_dummy], axis=1)
    click_rows = combined_df[combined_df.click == 1]
    no_click_rows = combined_df[combined_df.click == 0]
    no_click_rows = no_click_rows.sample(frac=1, replace=False, random_state=1)
    final_df = pd.concat([click_rows, no_click_rows], axis = 0)
    final_df = final_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    final_df = final_df.drop(['user_state', 'device_maker', 'day_of_week'], axis = 1)
    
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(final_df.drop(['click'], axis = 1), final_df['click'], test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
    
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    logmodel = LogisticRegression()
    logmodel.fit(x_train,y_train)
    predictions = logmodel.predict(x_test)
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

Comment: What do you think the result should be instead? Why?

Comment: What is the actual question, @chez? Please have a look at [ask], to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my suggestions:

1. You are missing [`stratify`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) argument in `train_test_split` function. It ensures the target distribution is similar in train/val/test data.
2. Logistic Regression doesn't well in detecting non-linear patterns in data. Try a tree based model like [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).